# Python, OpenCV, Raspberry Pi-3 - Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, virtualenv

I keep encountering an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "/home/pi/ball-track/ball_tracking.py", line 52, in <module>
  frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 45, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody experiencing the same issue I have resolved the error by typing the command:

```
  sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```